# How to force inline-block elements to parent's top?

Tags: html, css

Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/kdcmq/86/

```
#parent {
position: relative;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
background: red;    
}

#child {
display:inline-block;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: blue;
top: 0;
left: 100%    
}
```

I want to make the smaller blue elements to start when the bigger one starts, so the blue elements would be right below the border of the parent div. Is that possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have duplicate IDs in your code. IDs must be unique. Use classes instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the vertical-align property

```
vertical-align:top;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kdcmq/88/

Comment: Thank you, it looks like how I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

You will need *position: absolute* on #child. I think you also want *left: 0*, not 100%.

There is no need for #child to be *inline-block*. Make it *block*.

BTW This is the direct answer to your question. Whether what you are trying to do is good practice is another question...

Answer (score 0):

So you have a number of problems:

1. You cannot do 3 elements with id 'child', make them a class
2. top and left attributes don't mean anything unless `position:absolute`
3. You cannot remove spacing. A short Google search would reveal this: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

Yo can also float your elements

```
.child {
float:left;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin:0 10px 0 0;
background: blue;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AgX62/

(Changed your duplicate IDs to classes)